# Use temporary inside another temporary table in Oracle 18

Tags: oracle, temporary, oracle18c

is possible in Oracle18, to use a temporary table inside another temporary table?
Example below:

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ora$ptt_today_sales 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE DEFINITION
AS
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date = SYSDATE;


CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ora$information 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE DEFINITION
AS
SELECT * FROM ora$ptt_today_sales WHERE customerID=5;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on Live SQL (livesql.oracle.com) (which - true - runs Oracle 19c) and, as I though, **it works OK**, no problem.

However, the second code you wrote won't work as private temporary table name should begin with `ora$ptt_`, the same prefix you used for the first table.

That prefix is defined by the `PRIVATE_TEMP_TABLE_PREFIX` initialisation parameter. Its default value is `ora$ptt_` (just like in your first `CREATE TABLE` statement). As you most probably didn't change it between those two commands, use the same prefix for the second table as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, finally I have the development server online with the v18 running!, ok, the thing is, the easy example works fine, then problem is when I use the private temporary table inside a SQL with several joins, then I receive the error:00000 -  "error signaled in parallel query server %s"
*Cause:    A parallel query server reached an exception condition.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, I don't know why you got that error (I should Google for it, but you did that already). Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist.